# java2ws: retaining request response namespace in wsdl

Tags: jax-ws

I am running java2ws through a maven plugin. I find that the resulting wsdl does not
retain the namespace for the Request / Response object tree. I am wondering what kind of setup
/ annotation I can set to allow this to happen?

Ex,

```
@WebService(name = "MyService")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface IMyService extends MyBase {
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "mypackage.response")
public MyResponse findNames(
@WebParam(targetNamespace = "mypackage.request") MyRequest request);
}
```

Running java2ws generates,

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://mypackage/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://mypackage/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">    
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://mypackage/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://mypackage/">
```

Whereas, I would expect,

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"  xmlns:impl="urn:mypackage"
xmlns:intf="urn:mypackage" xmlns:tns1="http://request.mypackage"  xmlns:tns5="http://response.mypackage"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:mypackage">
```

Please share your thoughts on what kind of settings can lead me to the expected wsdl. Thank you.

Comment: The namespace issue / concern is resolved by adding the JAXB @XmlType annotation to the Request and Response classes. However, now that the wsdl brings in the respective namespaces, it is being generated without the <wsdl:binding> and <wsdl:service> elements. I am wondering if I need to set any additional flags for the Java2WS call when using explicit JAXB annotations? Thanks.

Comment: The wsdl generation was being aborted - it appears, due to a missing targetNamespace specification on the SEI impl class. When I specified the targetNamespace on the SEI, the impl class as well as in the call to java2ws - the expected wsdl was generated.